# Switch from one to another SVN server?

Tags: intellij-idea

I moved SVN repository from one cloud service to another. Did the full dump on old server and loaded it into a new service.

How can I now switch to the new SVN repository in IDEA?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-subversion-integration.html

Comment: A already have used 1 repo, now I have to move to another repo.

Comment: @alfasin This link is what I need: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-subversion-repository-location.html ?